# How to print text as italicized on a text file?

Tags: c, string, text, printf, file-processing

I'm making a program that asks the user to input citation info (i.e. author names, article title, journal title, volume number) as strings. It will then process that info to convert it into the proper APA 7th edition citation and ultimately print that into a text file (this will be done with fprintf). The problem is that certain info -- namely journal title and volume number -- need to be italicized but as far as I know, fprintf is incapable of printing formatted text so italicization is quite impossible.

My question is, are there any ways to make a particular string come out as italicized in a text file? Is C even capable of doing that with its standard libraries?

Comment: What encoding do you want to use for your output file?  Do you want some kind of unicode encoding?  Or do you want to use an HTML format or something along those lines?  You clearly don't want ASCII, so you need to make a choice.

Comment: It's not about printf being incapable. The plain regular text files can't store italic text. You need a different format, such as HTML or Markdown.

Comment: For [Epson FX](http://lprng.com/RESOURCES/EPSON/epson.htm): `printf("\x1B\x34%s\x1B\x35", title);`

Comment: fprintf can write anything to a file, including italicized text. The problem is that you need a file format able to store formatted text. Simple text file can't. You could use RTF or PDF or DOC/DOCX file format.

Comment: For completeness, competing against DOC/DOCX: ODT.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. Firstly, I opened (or rather created) a file named "citations.html" with the write operation. Then, I added multiple fprintf statements to write the file in such a way that it would be read in HTML format. Here's the code snippet below:

```
fp = fopen("citations.html", "w");

    fprintf(fp, "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n");
    fprintf(fp, "<html>\n");
    fprintf(fp, "<body>\n");

    for(i=0;i<articleNum;i++)
        fprintf(fp, "<p>%s (%d). %s. <i>%s, %d</i>(%d), %d-%d. %s</p>\n", articles[i].authors_list, articles[i].year, articles[i].articleTitle, 
                                                            articles[i].periodicalTitle, articles[i].volNum, articles[i].issNum,
                                                            articles[i].pageMin, articles[i].pageMax, articles[i].link);

    fprintf(fp, "</body>\n");
    fprintf(fp, "</html>");

    fclose(fp);
```

Note that the strings and integers that will be printed are stored as members of an array of structures.

Upon calling the function that contains this code, the program now generates an html file which can be opened with a browser. The browser will display the text -- complete with italicizations -- and can even be copy-pasted to MS Word with the formatting in tact.

Thank you all for the clarifications. It seems that I had completely misunderstood how text files work but at least that's all cleared up now.

Comment: Warning: if`authors_list`value is something like  "Peter AKA <Ex_ME>", it won't be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of code using `fprintf` creating a **file** with italicized text. The file is in [Rich Text Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) that can be opened with a lot of word processing applications including WordPad and Word.

The file will contain (Note the italicized part):

> This is *an example* of text.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char* fn = "e:\\temp\\document1.rtf";
    FILE* fp = fopen(fn, "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror(fn);
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(fp, "%s\n", "{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\nouicompat\\deflang1036");
    fprintf(fp, "%s\n", "{ \\fonttbl");
    fprintf(fp, "%s\n", "{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Calibri; }");
    fprintf(fp, "%s\n", "}");
    fprintf(fp, "%s\n", "\\viewkind4\\uc1");
    fprintf(fp, "%s\n", "\\pard\\sa200\\sl276\\slmult1\\f0\\fs22\\lang12 ");
    fprintf(fp, "%s\n", "This is \\i an example \\i0 of text.\\par");
    fprintf(fp, "%s\n", "\\par");
    fprintf(fp, "%s\n", "}");

    fclose(fp);
    printf("Document \"%s\" generated\n", fn);
}
```

The easiest to find out which RTF code to use is to create a document using WordPad and then look at it using NotePad. Note pad will show you the RTF source code for the document you created while WordPad will *render* the RTF code to display the formatting.

Comment: We have a similar solution but I decided to use HTML instead of RTF.

Comment: OK, good. You could have accepted my answer: fair since I gave you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to italicize pure text, there are some Unicode blocks including italicized characters [Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols) and they should be displayed correctly if your system support them. There are [converters online](https://capitalizemytitle.com/italic-text-generator/#) to convert pure text to italicized characters, but I don't know whether anyone already wrote the code somewhere...